# Are Pokémon in Spanish eggs different to UK eggs?

Tags: pokemon-go

heading off to Ibiza, and wondered if anyone knew of the likelihood of getting different Pokémon from eggs found in Spain as opposed to U.K. Ones. Just to see whether I have a hatch-off while not visiting poke stops to leave space for Spanish ones.

Comment: Eggs would be the same except for the regional pokemon, UK and spain are in the same region so there should be no difference afaik

Answer (score 1):

The eggs would be the same, I believe

Comment: @Vemonus then the eggs would be exactly the same

Comment: @Vemonus I'm editing my answer now